# MATCH..AGAINST in where and order by clause but not in select

Tags: mysql, sql

Table t has FTS index on `col1, col2`. I want to sort the rows based on scores on matching with a term. But I don't want the scores to be displayed in the result.

I tried the following query but it gives an error.

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST(term1, term2) AS score ORDER BY score, col3`

Here `AS score` gives an error.

Only this seems to work:

`SELECT t.*, MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST(term1, term2) AS score FROM t WHERE MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST(term1, term2) ORDER BY score, col3`

Any ideas how can use the `MATCH..AGAINST` query in where and order by clause without using it in the select list?

Comment: Repeat the expression in the order by clause

Comment: Does this mean the match.. against computation will happen twice/thrice for one row depending on the number of times I'm using it in the query?

Comment: That's unfortunately correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting @Shadow's suggestion.

We will have to repeat the expression in the order by clause.

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST(term1, term2) ORDER BY MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST(term1, term2), col3`

This would have repeated computation of `MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST(term1, term2)`.